# How to set up a Gitlab-runner using VirtualBox executor

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up a Gitlab specific runner using VirtualBox as an executor.

I'm using macOS 10.15.5 and here's what I did:

- Run `gitlab-runner register` and use URL and token shown in `Settings -> CI/CD`
- Choose `virtualbox` for executor
- Run `gitlab-runner start`

Then I can see the activated Runner in `Settings -> CI/CD` in my Gitlab project.

But if I commit the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, the runner pipeline fails with the following error:

```
Preparing the "virtualbox" executor
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): exec: "vboxmanage": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I tried everything to fix this based on Google search (especially tried everything from https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4590), but could not fix this.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your are talking about a local GitLab server, the first step would be to search for a  `vboxmanage` (of any case) on your system.

The second step would be to [troubleshoot the GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/), making sure its PATH includes `vboxmanage`

Comment: Thank you so much. I would appreciate it if you take a look at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63083624/5224286

Comment: @ZackLee Sure thing. I have added an answer to your new question.