# VirtualBox executer fails with “prepare environment: Process exited with status 1”

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, virtualbox, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I registered the VirtualBox CI runner using `gitlab-runner register` and by choosing `virtualbox` as an executor.

However, if I start the runner pipeline in Gitlab, it fails with the following error:

[image]

What would be causing this error and how to fix it?

Here's a link mentioned in the error message: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading

P.S: I'm using macOS 10.15.5 and the VirtualBox runs Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation mentions:

> For certain executors, the Runner will pass the `--login` flag as shown above, which also loads the shell profile.
> Anything that you have in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_logout`, or any other dotfile, will be executed in your job.
>
> If a job fails on the Prepare environment stage, it is likely that something in the shell profile is causing the failure. A common failure is when you have a `.bash_logout` that tries to clear the console.

So check first the content of your `.bashrc`, `.bash_logout`, or any other dotfile in the VM machine `$HOME` account.

The fact that step is marked as a "system failure" means you are using GitLab 13.1 (June 2020), per [Merge Request 1915](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/1915).

> Having this marked as a system failure would make it more clear to the
> user that the problem is with the Runner environment, we add a link to
> the documentation to make it more simple for them to understand what
> might be going on.

The same MR gives a good illustration of what a problem might be:

> The easiest way to test this is to use the [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html).
>
> 1. Update your bash profile to exit with error:
>
>    ```
>    echo "exit 1" > ~/.bash_logout
>    ```
> 2. Run `gitlab-runner` as the user that has the `.bash_logut` with the `exit 1` command
> 3. If you want to see the error in the `master` branch, make sure you have an empty /builds directory so that you can see the error: `cd No such file or directory` error on `master`.

Again: if, on your  `.bashrc`/`.bash_logout`, or any other dotfile in the VM machine `$HOME` account, there is a command which fails (status error != 0), that would trigger that error message.